# Is there a tool which can be used to simulate a daemon process to occupy a port?

Tags: testing, daemon, firewall

For example, can I use run 'ssh' as a backend daemon which occupies a port? But the real purpose is a test for the connection.

There could be multiple reasons which block the connection, the firewall in the two sides or something between them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use netcat to simulate a deamon listening on a service:

```
netcat -l 4444
```

With this command, netcat will listen (-l) on port 4444!
On the remote machine you then can use netcat again to test the comunication:

```
netcat domain.com 4444
```

where domain.com is the machine you set netcat to listen on the 4444 port!

I use this technique very often to test comunications on VM's!

Hope i was able to help!